# Custom Taxonomies and parents

Tags: custom-taxonomy

How can I create a group of custom taxonomies with parents that would include a description for the parent and child taxonomy?

Here's what I have so far.  The parent and child are created with the descriptions but the child taxonomy is not listed under the parent.

```
$categories = array(
   'Category 01'=>'<a href="http://category01.com" target="_blank">Category 01</a>',
    );

foreach($categories as $category => $cat_desc){
    wp_insert_term(
      $category, // the term 
     'style', // the taxonomy
      array(
        'description'=> $cat_desc,
        'slug' => $category ,
      )
    );
};

// List out all Categories with subcategories
$styles = array(
    'Category 01' => array(
        'Subcategory 1A'  => 'Subcategory 1A Description<br><a href="http://www.category01/subcategory.php#1a" target="_blank">Subcategory 1A Description</a>', 
        'Subcategory 1B'  => 'Subcategory 1B Description<br><a href="http://www.category01/subcategory.php#1a" target="_blank">Subcategory 1B Description</a>', 
        'Subcategory 1C'  => 'Subcategory 1C Description<br><a href="http://www.category01/subcategory.php#1a" target="_blank">Subcategory 1C Description</a>',
        'Subcategory 1D'  => 'Subcategory 1D Description<br><a href="http://www.category01/subcategory.php#1a" target="_blank">Subcategory 1D Description</a>',
        'Subcategory 1E'  => 'Subcategory 1E Description<br><a href="http://www.category01/subcategory.php#1a" target="_blank">Subcategory 1E Description</a>',            
    )             
);

// Import each array as taxonomy with parent
foreach($styles as $bjcp_category => $bjcp_styles ){
$parent_term = term_exists( $bjcp_category , 'style' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given
$parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id']; // get numeric term id
foreach($bjcp_styles as $bjcp_style => $bjcp_style_desc){
    wp_insert_term(
        $bjcp_style, // the term 
        'style', // the taxonomy
        array(
          'description'=> $bjcp_style_desc,
          'slug' => $bjcp_style,
          'parent'=> $parent_term_id
        )
    );
}
```

I have a feeling that I'm creating the arrays in a less than efficient method.  What would be the best way to accomplish this as I have over 100 custom taxonomies to import into my CPT and would like to have it done in one plugin.

My question is, how would I structure an array to include the parent and child taxonomies with descriptions for each?

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to know how to create the array? (<-- off-topic most likely) Or do you want know how to import your taxonomies? If so, what is the source for the import? CSV? Another database? What does the data look like? And exactly what needs to import?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to import a set of taxonomies that include children.  I have the source in an Excel spreadsheet but would prefer not to use another plugin to import them.  Yes, I know how to create a basic array.  Where I'm having trouble is figuring out how to create an array that will import both taxonomies and child taxonomies with descriptions in each.